# Merging two data frames, while keeping uncommon rows between them using R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two `dfs` as below and want to merge. I want to merge these two dfs based on the family column and add the count for each gene without removing the genes in the final df if they are not common between the first df and the second one.

```
#first df
Family <- c("LET-7","LET-7","LET-7","MIR-10","MIR-103","MIR-124","MIR-124","MIR-124")
Sequence <- c("ATCGGCA","ATGCTAC","ATCGGCA","ATCGTTT","TGAGGAG","TGATCAG","AATTCAG","AATTCAG")
my_data_frame <- data.frame(Family,Sequence)
```

```
#second df
counts <- c("2","3")
Family <- c("LET-7","MIR-124")
countdf <- data.frame(Family,counts)
```

the output that I want to have

```
Family <- c("LET-7","LET-7","LET-7","MIR-10","MIR-103","MIR-124","MIR-124","MIR-124")
Counts <- c("2","2","2","0","0","3","3","3")
Sequence <- c("ATCGGCA","ATGCTAC","ATCGGCA","ATCGTTT","TGAGGAG","TGATCAG","AATTCAG","AATTCAG")
newdf <- data.frame(Family,Counts,Sequence)
```

Comment: You might want to initialize your data.frames with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` , that prevents some inconveniences later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using package `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
newdf_dplyr <- my_data_frame %>% 
  left_join(countdf)
```

Solution using base R:

```
newdf_base <- merge(my_data_frame, countdf, by="Family", all.x=TRUE)
```